# ffmpeg map filter option

Tags: ffmpeg

What does below ffmpeg option do?

```
 -map [v] -map [a]
```

and

```
 -map 0
```

I have read [this](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-Video-options) but still not able to understand exactly what it does and when to use them?

Answer (score 5):

The `-map` option can refer to arbitrary stream labels or specific input streams.

- `-map [v] -map [a]` – Select the streams arbitrarily labeled `v` and `a`. For example, these could be the outputs of filtering:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw/2:-1[v];[0:a]afade=d=5[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output
  ```
- `-map 0` – Select all streams from input 0. `ffmpeg` begins counting from 0, so this is the first input; using `-map 4` would refer to the fifth input. Because the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior only chooses one stream per stream type, using `-map 0` is useful if you want to select all streams from input 0. Example:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -map 0 -map 1 output
  ```

Also see:

- [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map)

Comment: When omitting the output pads `[v]` and `[a]`, I don't have to use `map` and still get the same result:
`ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw/2:-1;[0:a]afade=d=5" output`
According to the docs `[...] if the output label of the last filter is not specified, "out" is assumed. [...]`. Is this equally valid or is this bad practice?

Comment: Oh my. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki is the missing manual, right in front of my face the whole time.